# Is there an ANSI control sequence which moves the cursor to the end of line?

Tags: ansi-escape

I know of `\33[nC` which moves the cursor `n` columns forward; the problem is, I don't know how many characters the particular line consists of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such ANSI control sequence.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing **explicit**, however screens are "small", and you could use any of the cursor-movement commands to move to an arbitrarily far destination and the terminal will limit the movement by the screen's size.

For instance, the cursor-forward (in terminfo, **`cuf`**) control uses a repeat-count, and horizontal position absolute (in terminfo, **`hpa`**) control uses a column value.  Either of these should work for you:

```
tput cuf 999
tput hpa 999
```

(assuming that your screen has fewer than a thousand columns).  There are others which may be implemented in your terminal (emulator...), but those are fairly common.

By the way, for hardcoding, **`cuf`** is the same as the example in the question.  That's ***columns***, not ***lines*** which are moved.  To move the cursor by ***lines***, you would use **`cud`** (<kbd>escape> [</kbd>*n*<kbd>**B**</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

If there was a line end then you could save it with `\033[s`. And then, after you've done manipulating the line, restore the position with `\033[u`.

Comment: True, but most of the terminals do not support these two escape sequences.

Comment: @rido give an example

Comment: rxvt, kvt, xiterm, Eterm, and mine (xterm-256color) also does not support. check the [link](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html). You can check your terminal with 'echo $TERM' or 'echo $COLORTERM'

Comment: @rido Your terminal should except the codes as xterm mentioned as one in your link. Mine is xterm-256color exactly like yours, and it works perfectly. And, as far as understand, xterm is the 'most of the terminals'.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar problem, I have managed to work around the necessity of explicitly knowing `n` in `\33[nC` by obtaining its value in my program and using **string interpolation** to put the value of the variable `n` into a string containing the aforementioned escape sequence.

This isn't a universal solution, however, as there might be cases where `n` cannot be determined so easily.

Comment: "explicitly knowing n in \33[nC by obtaining its value in my program" Could you explain it more? I have a similar problem. Did you get the number from keyboard events or terminal buffer? Or somehow different.

Comment: I do not remember the exact issue, it has been years. But in my case I was able to determine the length of each line from the internal functioning of my program. I stored the value in a variable and used something like `"\33[${myVariable}C"` in my code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI command `\33[1000C`
This will send the cursor 1,000 columns to the right. If there aren't 1,000 colums it just hits the end of the line and stays there. It doesn't wrap around. It's a bit of a brute force method but it works well and easy enough for what I've been doing.